# Prove that $\text{span}\left\{u_1+...+u_l\right\}+\text{span}\left\{v_1+...+v_k\right\}=\text{span}\left\{u_1+...+u_l,v_1+...+v_k\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As the title says. My version of the proof is:

Let $\alpha_i$ be scalars, so if $U=span\left\{u_1+...+u_l\right\}$ and $V=span\left\{v_1+...+v_k\right\}$.

We have $u+v=\alpha_1 u_1+...+\alpha_l u_l+\alpha'_1 v_1+...+\alpha'_k v_k$.

These are the vectors are in $span\left\{u_1+...+u_l,v_1+...+v_k\right\}$.

I'm not sure if it is correct, if it is what is the proof of the converse?

Comment: What does the $+$ mean in $\operatorname{span}(S) + \operatorname{span}(T)$?

Comment: There are only two vectors of interest in this question, namely $u_1+\cdots+u_l$ (call it$~u$) and $v_1+\cdots+v_k$ (call it$~v$). This is probably not what you mean. But literally you are asking to show that $\def\sp{\operatorname{span}}\sp\{u\}+\sp\{v\}=\sp\{u,v\}$. Which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.

This is merely a set theoretic verification. As Marc van Leeuwen said, it is enough to prove for two vectors.. That is,

$$span\{u\}+span\{v\}=span\{u+v\}$$
 Let, $x\in span\{u\}+span\{v\}$

$\iff$ there exists, $y\,\&\,z$ such that $x=y+z,y\in span\{u\}, z\in span\{v\}$

$\iff$ i.e, there exists, $\alpha,\beta$ such that, $x=\alpha u+\beta v$

$\iff x\in span\{u,v\}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the problem is simply
$$
\text{span}\{u\}+\text{span}\{v\}=\text{span}\{u,v\}.$$

Comment: What's the sum of spans defined as?

Comment: @GFauxPas, sum of vector subspaces: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Combining_Subspaces.

Comment: So is my proof incorrect?

Comment: @Yuan, is correct (in fact all the $\alpha_i$ are equal and ditto por the $\alpha'_i$). My point is that the long sums are a distraction.